# Codeigniter MySQL Connection

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

As per my knowledge, if I connect `MySQL`, I have to close the connection immediately after executing the script otherwise it will stay opened.

My question is does `codeigniter` close the `MySQL` connection each time after executing the script? If not, how do I perform it ?

Comment: `$this->db->close();`
very simple

Comment: make sure persistent connection is set to false in config file `$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;`. Default value is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Codeigniter close connection automatically as said in manual
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html#manually-closing-the-connection

But if you want to close explicitly you can

```
$this->db->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter closes its database connection. 
But to manually do that within your class you can use the following

```
$this->db->close();
```

Read here for more information 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

It should do yes. But its good practice to close it any way.

```
$connect->close();
```

---

$connect being:

```
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```